# iOS: Change appearance of UIView only (no subclasses) - possible?

Tags: ios, uiappearance

I have a project with many view controllers, and I want all of them to have parent views with a tiled background image. Now I could do

```
[[UIView appearance] setBackgroundColor:
    [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackgroundPattern"]]];
```

The problem is, this will also set background of all other `UIView` subclassing objects (`UIButtons`, `UILabels`, etc.). What can I do to just change the `UIView` background?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the `appearance` proxy at a class level there's no choice. You're going to modify every `UIView` subclass.

I don't see many other options to subclassing `UIViewController`, changing the appearence of that subclass' view only and then making all the others `UIViewController` subclass of the first one.

Comment: +1 for the answer, although it's not was hoping for :( thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

You could create Categories on each type, and add a UIAppearance selector that sets the corner radius.

UIView+Appearance.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (Appearance)
- (void)setCornerRadius:(CGFloat)cornerRadius UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;

@end
```

UIView+Appearance.m file:

```
#import "UIView+Appearance.h"

@implementation UIView (Appearance)
- (void)setCornerRadius:(CGFloat)cornerRadius {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;
}

@end
```

AppDelegate.m file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ViewController class], nil] setCornerRadius:5.0];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you could create a subclass of UIViewController calling it something like MyTiledViewController and in the init/viewDidLoad method write this...

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackgroundPattern"]]];
```

**EDIT:**
looks like Gabriele Petronella beat me to it, same thing really.

Comment: +1 for the answer, although it's not was hoping for :( thanks anyway!